# Rendering a side by side comparison using knockout

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm working on a project where I would like to be able to display several items side by side for comparison.

I'd like to have the comparison displayed similarly to the way in which amazon does, with each item being represented by a vertical column with all of the info about the item in that column:

[image]

I'm currently using Knockout, and have an Observable array with the items I would like to compare.  I would like to use the foreach binding to do the job and my problem stems from the fact that table's have all cells for a specific row contained in the same element which makes it difficult to use:

```
<tr>
  <td>Rating</td>
  <td> 4.5 (data from item 1)</td>
  <td> 3.5 (data from item 2)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>price</td>
  <td>$2.3 (data from item 1) </td>
  <td>$3.5 (data from item 2) </td>
</td>
```

If I wanted each item to be contained in a row this would not be a problem.
Anyone have any recommendations for how to tackle this issue since the data for different items has to exists in different (overlapping) parts of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have bad news for you. Html tables are strictly ordered in rows, and this kind of layout for your data can be a bit frustrating.

You have two options, basically:

**Option A: Transpose your data**

You could introduce a specific View Model for a "Feature-Comparison" and transpose your data to that. You can then do a `foreach` on your `tbody` iterating through those "featureComparisons". In code, here's what I mean:

```js
var inputData = [
  { name: "First product", rating: 4.5, price: "$3.50", color: "Gray" },
  { name: "Another product", rating: 3.5, price: "$2.95", color: "Yellow" }
];

function FeatComparison(comparisonName, comparedValues) {
  this.comparisonName = comparisonName;
  this.comparedValues = comparedValues;
}

var vm = { comparisons: ko.observableArray([]) };

// You could also explicitly send a list of comparable properties from back-end.
// For this example we iterate the first product.
for (var prop in inputData[0]) {
  if (inputData[0].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    var vals = inputData.map(function(i) { return i[prop]; });
    vm.comparisons.push(new FeatComparison(prop, vals));
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
td { background: #eee; padding: 5px 10px; }
tr:first-child, td:first-child { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table><tbody data-bind="foreach: comparisons">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: comparisonName"></td>
    <!-- ko foreach: comparedValues -->
    <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

This option is best suited for situations where you want to make an extended comparison feature with things like comparing multiple products, saving user preferences on what features to include or not, etc.

**Option B: Deal with it** (for lack of a better title)

Just leave your data as is, and iterate through both objects with `foreach` at the same time. In code:

```js
var inputData = [
  { name: "First product", rating: 4.5, price: "$3.50", color: "Gray" },
  { name: "Another product", rating: 3.5, price: "$2.95", color: "Yellow" }
];

function RootVm(data) {
  var self = this;
  this.products = ko.observableArray(data);
  this.keys = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.products().length === 0) return [];
    return Object.keys(self.products()[0]);
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootVm(inputData));
```

```css
td { background: #eee; padding: 5px 10px; }
tr:first-child, td:first-child { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<table><tbody data-bind="foreach: keys">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.products -->
    <td data-bind="text: $data[$parent]"></td>
    <!-- /ko -->
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```